# a point divides a line in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

In a I studied that in a book[image]

In that I cannot understand how they have written MA = k. MB

And what the significance of value of k that is when itvis positive,negative and zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In that I cannot understand how they have written $\overrightarrow{MA} = k  \cdot \overrightarrow{MB}$.

$M$ is assumed to be collinear with $A,B$, therefore the vectors $\overrightarrow{MA}$ and $\overrightarrow{MB}$ are linearly dependent. This means that there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$, not both of them zero, such that $p \cdot \overrightarrow{MA} + q \cdot \overrightarrow{MB} = 0$. For $M \not \equiv B$ this implies that the ratio of the signed segments $\frac{MA}{MB} = -\frac{q}{p}$.

But $k$ has been defined as the ratio into which $M$ divides $AB$, so $-\frac{q}{p} = k$, thus $\overrightarrow{MA} = k \cdot \overrightarrow{MB}$.

> And what the significance of value of $k$ that is when itvis positive,negative and zero.

- $k=0$ iff $MA=0 \iff M \equiv A$.
- $k \lt 0$ iff the segments $MA$ and $MB$ have opposite orientation, which happens when (and only when) the point $M$ is *between* $A$ and $B$.
- $k \gt 0$ iff $MA$ and $MB$ have the same orientation i.e. $M$ is *outside* the segment $[AB]$. 
  If $k \in (0,1)$ then $M$ is on the same side of $B$ as $A$, else if $k \gt 1$ it is on the opposite side.

As a side note, the definition $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ excludes the value $1$ because there exist no point $M$ on line $AB$ such that the ratio of the signed segments $\frac{MA}{MB} = 1$. (*Sketch of proof:* $1 \gt 0$, *so* $M$ *would need to lie outside segment* $[A,B]$. *Suppose WLOG that* $M$ *is on the same side of* $B$ *as* $A$. *Then* $MB=MA+AB \gt MA$, *therefore* $k = \frac{MA}{MB} \lt 1$.)